# Tensorflow execution time

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I have a function within a Python script that I am calling multiple times (https://github.com/sankhaMukherjee/NNoptExpt/blob/dev/src/lib/NNlib/NNmodel.py): I have simplified the function significantly for this example.

```
def errorValW(self, X, y, weights):

    errVal = None

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        nW = len(self.allW)
        W = weights[:nW] 
        B = weights[nW:]

        for i in range(len(W)):
            sess.run(tf.assign( self.allW[i], W[i] ))

        for i in range(len(B)):
            sess.run(tf.assign( self.allB[i], B[i] ))

        errVal = sess.run(self.err, 
            feed_dict = {self.Inp: X, self.Op: y})

    return errVal
```

I am calling this function many times from another function. When I see the program log, It appears that this function keeps taking longer and longer. A partial log is shown:

```
21:37:12,634 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.477610e+00 seconds
21:37:14,116 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.481470e+00 seconds
21:37:15,608 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.490914e+00 seconds
21:37:17,113 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.504651e+00 seconds
21:37:18,557 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.443876e+00 seconds
21:37:20,183 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.625608e+00 seconds
21:37:21,719 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 1.534915e+00 seconds
... many lines later  
22:59:26,524 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 9.576592e+00 seconds
22:59:35,991 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 9.466405e+00 seconds
22:59:45,708 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 9.716456e+00 seconds
22:59:54,991 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 9.282923e+00 seconds
23:00:04,407 - ... .errorValW ... - Finished the function [errorValW] in 9.415035e+00 seconds
```

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?? This is totally baffling to me ...

**Edit**: this is for reference ...

For reference, the initializer for the class is shown below. I suspect that the graph for the `result` variable is progressively increasing in size. I have seen this problem when I try to save models with `tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())` and the size of this file keeps increasing. I am not sure if I am making a mistake in defining the model in any way ...

```
def __init__(self, inpSize, opSize, layers, activations):

    self.inpSize = inpSize
    self.Inp     = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=inpSize, name='Inp')
    self.Op      = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=opSize, name='Op')

    self.allW    = []
    self.allB    = []

    self.result  = None

    prevSize = inpSize[0]
    for i, l in enumerate(layers):
        tempW = tf.Variable( 0.1*(np.random.rand(l, prevSize) - 0.5), dtype=tf.float32, name='W_{}'.format(i) )
        tempB = tf.Variable( 0, dtype=tf.float32, name='B_{}'.format(i) )

        self.allW.append( tempW )
        self.allB.append( tempB )

        if i == 0:
            self.result = tf.matmul( tempW, self.Inp ) + tempB
        else:
            self.result = tf.matmul( tempW, self.result ) + tempB

        prevSize = l

        if activations[i] is not None:
            self.result = activations[i]( self.result )

    self.err = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean((self.Op - self.result)**2))


    return
```

Comment: Are `X`, `y`, or `weights` growing as you train your model?

Comment: You should save timestamps multiple times in youf function to see what part is taking longer. Also, remember, when you measure time, to only save in a datastructure and do IO once at the end, so you don't affect the results

Comment: @chrisz : No, they are always the same size.

Comment: @Nyri0: Thanks, I'll try that to see where the problem might be ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `tf.assign` in the the session context. This will keep adding ops to your graph every time you execute the `errorValW` function, slowing down execution as your graph grows larger. As a rule of thumb, you should avoid ever calling Tensorflow ops when executing models on data (since this will usually be inside a loop, resulting in constant growth of the graph). From my personal experience, even if you are only adding "a few" ops during execution time this can result in extreme slowdown.

Note that `tf.assign` is an op like any other. You should define it once beforehand (when creating the model/building the graph) and then run the same op repeatedly after launching the session.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve in your code snippet, but consider the following:

```
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.assign(some_var, a_value))
```

could be replaced by

```
a_placeholder = tf.placeholder(type_for_a_value, shape_for_a_value)
assign_op = tf.assign(some_var, a_placeholder)
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_op, feed_dict={a_placeholder: a_value})
```

where `a_placeholder` should have the same dtype/shape as `some_var`. I have to admit I haven't tested this snippet so please let me know if there are issues, but this should be about right.