# Tensorflow tf.train.Saver not saving all variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I thought that Tensorflow saver will save all variables as stated here

> If you do not pass any arguments to tf.train.Saver(), the saver
>   handles all variables in the graph. Each variable is saved under the
>   name that was passed when the variable was created.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

However, the variable epochCount in my code below does not seem to get saved. This variable is used to keep track of the total epoches the model has trained over the data.

When I restore a graph it resets to it's initializer value, not the value it was when it the check point was last saved.

It appears to me that it's only saving variables used in calculating the loss.

Here's my code.

This is where I declare my graph:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): 

  valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(1, valid_window), valid_size)) #put inside graph to get new words each time

  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, cbow_window*2 ])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)
  valid_datasetSM = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0) #to store epoch count to total # of epochs are known

  embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', 
    initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

  softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights',
    initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
  softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', 
    initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),  trainable=False )

  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is
  embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*cbow_window*2, embedding_size] )
  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(cbow_window*2)
  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) #Original learning rate was 1.0

  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset) 
  similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings)) 

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

If I restore the graph from checkpoint, the embeddings, and softmax_biases are restored, but epochCount is reset to its initializer value.  (Note that I am not calling the tf.global_variables_initializer().run() line, which is a common cause of variables mistakenly being reset after a checkpoint has been restored)

Here is the code where the graph is run

```
num_steps = 1000001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

  saver.restore(session, './checkpointsBook2VecCbowWindow2Downloaded/bookVec.ckpt' )
  average_loss = 0
  saveIteration = 1
  for step in range(1, num_steps):

    batch_data, batch_labels = generate_batch(
      batch_size, cbow_window)
    feed_dict = {train_dataset : batch_data, train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict) 

    if step % 20000 == 0:
      recEpoch_indexA =  epoch_index - recEpoch_indexA
      epochCount = tf.add(  epochCount, recEpoch_indexA, name=None )
      recEpoch_indexA = epoch_index

      save_path = saver.save(session, "checkpointsBook2VecCbowWindow2/bookVec.ckpt") 
      chptName = 'B2VCbowW2Embed256ckpt'+str(saveIteration)
      zipfolder(chptName, 'checkpointsBook2VecCbowWindow2')
      uploadModel.SetContentFile(chptName+".zip")
      uploadModel.Upload()

      print("Checkpoint uploaded to Google Drive")
      saveIteration += 1
```

This is the code I use to print out all the variables saved in a checkpoint after training. I restore the graph and print out all the variables saved.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./MODEL/bookVec.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, './MODEL/bookVec.ckpt' )
  for v in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection("variables"):
    print('From variables collection ', v)
```

And this is the output from the code above

```
From variables collection  <tf.Variable 'embeddings:0' shape=(10001, 256) dtype=float32_ref>
From variables collection  <tf.Variable 'softmax_weights:0' shape=(10001, 256) dtype=float32_ref>
From variables collection  <tf.Variable 'softmax_biases:0' shape=(10001,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

As seen, epochCount has not been saved.

Comment: Chances are this is because it's never actually used in the graph. You are only using it in the training loop. BTW it's considered bad practice to call TF ops (`tf.add` in this case) after the session has been launched and especially within the training loop.

Comment: Wow thanks for this info! "BTW it's considered bad practice to call TF ops (tf.add in this case) after the session has been launched and especially within the training loop" why is this? Also, is there a more established way to keep track of the total number of epoches?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281664/tensorflow-execution-time/49298059#49298059) for the TF thing (in your case it's not that dramatic since you only do it once per epoch). As for how to keep track of the epochs, I will put this into an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the variable is restored as 0 is because it is actually never updated (i.e. it *is* restored correctly)! You are overwriting `epochCount` by the `tf.add` call during the session, which only returns the operation, no actual value. That is, the variable (in the Tensorflow sense) is "orphaned" and will stay at 0 forever.

You could use `tf.assign` to update the variable instead. It could look something like this:

```
# where you define the graph
epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0)
update_epoch = tf.assign(epochCount, epochCount + 1)
...
# after you launched the session
for step in range(1, num_steps):
    if step % 20000 == 0:
        sess.run(update_epoch)
```

Comment: Thanks! 1 more question: does this eliminate the issue you mentioned earlier about "to call TF ops (tf.add in this case) after the session has been launched and especially within the training loop" since the operation is called using sess.run(update_epoch)? My interpretation is that in my original code, I was trying to change a tensorflow variable directly in the python enviroment while a session was being run on the same graph where that variable was defined. In your code, now the variable is being changed within the same session being run. Or is it something else?

Comment: My original comment to your question was actually kind of misleading, sorry. One problem was that you merely called the `tf.add` function, which only "creates" the operation to add, but does no actual adding. By using `sess.run` we actually do the adding. However, your original formulation was also broken due to overwriting the `tf.Variable` by something else. Even if you were to `run` the `tf.add`, this would overwrite the _Python_ variable holding your `tf.Variable` by another value, not update the TF variable. As a rule of thumb, if you want to update a TF variable, use `tf.assign`.